# Number of occurrences of unique rows in a file

Tags: bash, unique, rows

Assume a file has the following rows:

```
aa bbb cccc dddd
eee ffff ggggg
aa bbb cccc dddd
i jj kkk llll
aa bbb cccc dddd
eee ffff ggggg
```

Is there any bash command to determine how many times unique rows in the file have occurred? The output should be:

```
aa bbb cccc dddd 3 time
eee ffff ggggg 2 times
i jj kkk llll 1 time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine a couple of commands:

```
sort <inputfile | uniq -c
```

The man page for `uniq` starts with:

```
NAME
       uniq - report or omit repeated lines

SYNOPSIS
       uniq [OPTION]... [INPUT [OUTPUT]]

DESCRIPTION
       Discard all but one of successive identical lines from INPUT
       (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).

       -c, --count
              prefix lines by the number of occurrences
```

So the output for your given input file is:

```
  3 aa bbb cccc dddd
  2 eee ffff ggggg
  1 i jj kkk llll
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the number of occurrences as a suffix rather preceded by a comma rather than as a prefix?

Comment: Yes, it is. The `uniq` command won't do that by itself, but you could do that pretty easily using something like `sed` or `awk`.